# Get the list of characters added to a file

Tags: python, difflib

I have an original file and another one that contains some extra characters.  I am looking for the list of characters added to this file. I tried to use difflib but I have errors because characters can be inserted in the middle of a word.

```
import difflib

with open('file1') as f1:
    f1_text = f1.read()
with open('file2') as f2:
    f2_text = f2.read()

differ = difflib.Differ()
diffs = list(differ.compare(f1_text, f2_text))

lines = list(diffs)
removed = [line[1:] for line in lines if line[0] == '-']
f = open("results", "a")
f.write(''.join(removed))
```

File1

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

File2

> LRorFem ipsum docdlor sit avcvcmet, consGecte5tur adiFbpiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo cocdnseqduat. Duis aute irure dolor in
> reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
> pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
> culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Result

> R F c d c v c m t c o n s G e c t e 5 t r   a d F p i s c i n g   e l
> i t ,   s e d   d  e i u s m o d   t e m p o   n c i d i d u n t u t
> l a b o r e   e t   d o l o r e   m a g a a .   U t   e n m a d  m i n
> i m   v n i a m , u i s   n o s t r u d   e x e r c i t a t i o n   u
> l l a m c o   l a b o r i s   n i s i   u t  a l i q u i p   e x   e a
> c o m m o d o   c o c d n s e q d

Expected Result :
RFdcvcvcG5Fbcdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate through each file one character at a time

```
result = []

with open('file1') as file1, open('file2') as file2:
    ch1, ch2 = file1.read(1), file2.read(1)
    while ch1 and ch2:
        if ch1 == ch2:
            ch1, ch2 = file1.read(1), file2.read(1)
        else:
            result.append(ch2)
            ch2 = file2.read(1)

print(result)
```

```
['R', 'F', 'c', 'd', 'v', 'c', 'v', 'c', 'G', '5', 'F', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd']
```